# Unable to override onBackgroundActivated and OnSuspending events in Application class : Winui3

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, winui-3

I am creating a winui3 application and having the latest .net SDK 5.0403 but I'm unable to override `onBackgroundActivated`, `OnSuspending` events in the App class that extends the Application class. I have windows 10(version 19042), Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (v4.0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `OnLaunched` method is already overridden in the `App.xaml.cs` file that's included in the default WinUI 3 template in Visual Studio.

And `Suspending` is an event that cannot be overriden but handled in the same class/file assuming you target the [1.0.0-experimental1 release of the experimental channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/experimental-channel#version-10-experimental-100-experimental1?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) or later:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }


    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_window = new MainWindow();
        m_window.Activate();
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }

    private Window m_window;
}
```

Comment: still i can't use this getting the error "The name suspending does not exist in the current context"  on the Suspending.

Comment: Suspending/OnSuspending is absent in WinUI3 so you won't be able to use it

Comment: It's available in the [latest release of the experimental channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/experimental-channel#version-10-experimental-100-experimental1?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) which is currently 1.0.0-experimental1.